# Custom belongs_to attribute writer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

An application I'm working on, is trying to use the concept of polymorphism without using polymorphism.

```
class User
 has_many :notes
end

class Customer
 has_many :notes
end

class Note
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :customer
end
```

Inherently we have two columns on notes: `user_id` and `customer_id`, now the bad thing here is it's possible for a note to now have a `customer_id` and a `user_id` at the same time, which I don't want.

I know a simple/better approach out of this is to make the notes table polymorphic, but there are some restrictions, preventing me from doing that right now.

I'd like to know if there are some custom ways of overriding these associations to ensure that when one is assigned, the other is unassigned.

Here are the ones I've tried:

```
def user_id=(id)
  super
  write_attribute('customer_id', nil)
end

def customer_id=(id)
  super
  write_attribute('user_id', nil)
end
```

This doesn't work when using:

```
note.customer=customer or 
note.update(customer: customer)
```

but works when using:

```
note.update(customer_id: 12)
```

I basically need one that would work for both cases, without having to write 4 methods:

```
def user_id=(id)

end

def customer_id=(id)

end

def customer=(id)

end

def user=(id)

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use ActiveRecord callbacks to achieve such results.

```
class Note

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :customer

  before_save :correct_assignment

  # ... your code ...

  private

  def correct_assignment
    if user_changed?
      self.customer = nil
    elsif customer_changed?
      self.user = nil
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks. the issue with that is that before persisting a record, I'd have a record with the two states at once, therefore if I had something like a `before_save :do_something_to_owner`, the app gets confused as the 2 states currently exist and order dependent callbacks are bad. Another buggy area would be updating both fields at once, which would now always fallback to the first branch, now assume I'm only updating the field to be nil, then I'd also need to be checking the argument again. Seems like a good solution, though, but I think it presents more bugs later. I think I'd go explicit here